# #include <algorithm> fatal error in linux C++

Tags: linux, algorithm, g++, linux-mint

I've compiled the same code (MozJpeg project https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg ) without problems in Windows but I didn't manage to do it in Linux since it requires "algorithm" header.

I've been searching about that header and it seems to be available in other systems not only in Windows but my compiler doesn't find it. Maybe it could be a really simple issue but I'm too newbie in Linux.

Notice that the project is generated using CMake and I'm trying to compile it using a simple make command.

Thank you in advance.

```
frank@TESTWORKSTATION:~/Escritorio/GitLayama/MozJpeg/buildlinux$ make
[  0%] Built target simd
[ 17%] Built target jpeg-static
[ 19%] Built target jpegtran-static
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/turbojpeg-static.dir/rdbmp.c.o
In file included from /home/frank/Escritorio/GitLayama/MozJpeg/rdbmp.c:29:
/home/frank/Escritorio/GitLayama/MozJpeg/cmyk.h:21:10: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory
21 | #include <algorithm>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/turbojpeg-static.dir/build.make:752: 
CMakeFiles/turbojpeg-static.dir/rdbmp.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:209: CMakeFiles/turbojpeg- 
static.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2

frank@TESTWORKSTATION:~/Escritorio/GitLayama/MozJpeg/buildlinux$
```

Comment: what compiler are you using?.

Comment: mozjpeg seems to be a C library. It won't use `<algorithm>`. That part seems a red herring

Comment: As I said I'm totally newbie to linux but I double checked that G++ is installed and concerning the compilation I just ran sudo make.

Comment: Recommendation: Capture the full output of a clean build and add it to the question. I can't give any guarantees that it'll help, but odds are pretty good that we can at least help narrow down the root cause.

Comment: @user4581301 added to the initial post!

Comment: I'd have to look at the file's commit log to see if someone <expletive deleted>ed up, but [currently cmyk.h doesn't `#include <algorithm>`](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg/blob/master/cmyk.h). Maybe re-pull? Just looked at the history. Untouched for years.

Comment: Take a look at the cmyk.h and make sure the include is really there. There's always the possibility that someone is playing silly preprocessor games.

Comment: @user4581301 There's always the possibility that someone is playing totally-not-silly games with your computer without you knowing it. Especially if you run commands like `sudo make`.

Comment: TL;DR your copy of `cmyk.h` does not appear to come from the repository. You may want to figure out how it ended up on your system.

Comment: Another take on n.m's point: [Reflections on Trusting Trust](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/358198.358210) Some jobs I work on I have to send the code to be compiled with the official build system in Germany. They compile it and send back the build output if it doesn't compile. Some other team (and I have no clue where they are) does all of the testing and updates the bug tracker. I never actually see the executable.

Answer (score 0):

As some users said the header was not ok I don't know what was the date of the incorrect repo, but re-downloading it from the last Git version worked ok.

Comment: Just out of interest, did the previous version of cmyk.h actually have `#include <algorithm>` on line 21?

Comment: Yes it does as I said, unfortunately, I don't know the date of that code.

Comment: Hopefully you just downloaded someone's custom-cooked version rather than an official build. All the same, I'd run an antivirus scan with phasers set to kill.